# Align link as long as possible to the right inside div

Tags: html, css

I want the link x to appear as long to the right as possible:

```
<div class="token" data-value="bad">

<span class="token-label" style="max-width: 897px;">

    sadfasfasf
</span>
<a class="close" tabindex="-1" href="#">

    ×
</a>

</div>

.tokenfield .token .close {
 font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.49em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: none;
  height: 100%;  
  vertical-align:top;
  padding-right: 4px;  
}
```

I have tried `float:right` and  `right:0px` but they did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS would do it:

```
position: absolute;
right:0;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5gMtJ/)**

Note though that your selector is incorrect. `.tokenfield .token .close` selects an element that has the class close that's a descendant of an element with the class token that's a descendant of an element with the class tokenfield.

Comment: Thanks! But it went outside the div, i want it to be as long to the right as posible inside the div.

Comment: Give your div a relative position. Then any absolutely positioned descendants will stay within the divs boundary.